# HTML5 <audio> tag - autoplay, even when the tab does not have focus

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio

I'm running a large, batch-processing page that takes anywhere between 1 and 10 minutes to load. Once the page finishes loading, I click Refresh to reload the page and do it automatically for the next batch. The whole process takes between 50 and 100 clicks, and sometimes up to 3 hours (don't ask, seriously...).

As I'm waiting so long, I set up the page to play an alert noise when the page loads. I put this in the body of the page:

```
<audio controls autoplay style="visibility:hidden;">
    <source src="http://mysite.com/ding-dong.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

It works great - but only when the tab has active focus. If I'm browsing elsewhere on the web, whilst waiting for the page to load, I'd still like to hear the alert when the page finishes loading.

Is this possible using the HTML5 `<audio>` tag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is disabled because of performance and power saving policy from version 46, see more in the [code review](https://codereview.chromium.org/1292433002), but from version 47 you can switch this chrome tag [#disable-gesture-requirement-for-media-playback](http://chrome://flags/#disable-gesture-requirement-for-media-playback). I've tested this on version 53 with success.

Comment: The flag does not exists anymore ? (chrome 60 here) - any other option ?

Comment: @gordie I found some mention about missing tag by mistake, probably next build will fix it (I have issues too). https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=728108#c2